# Word API: copy macros from one doc to an other doc

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation

Is it possible to copy the macros of an existing Word document to a newly created Word document by using the Word API?

I tried with C#. I know that is mandatory to change the trust level in Word to do so. I am also able to determine the document has macros.

But if I create a new document with C# it doesn't have a VBProject and is readonly.

Here is some code to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
Word.Document oldDoc = word.Documents.Open(oldFilePath);

if (!oldDoc.HasVBProject)
    return;

Word.Document newDoc = word.Documents.Add();
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

foreach (var component in oldDoc.VBProject.VBComponents)
{
    newDoc.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(component);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenXML seems to work for this purpose, see sample code from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ab65277e-f0fb-4f2b-bfdc-e141abb8404f/copy-macros-document-to-another-document?forum=oxmlsdk)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
namespace CtrlInsertMacro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument destDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create("destination.docm", WordprocessingDocumentType.MacroEnabledDocument))
            {
            WordprocessingDocument srcDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("macrosource.docm", false);
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = destDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            // Create the document structure and add some text.
            mainPart.Document = new Document();
            Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
            Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text("This is a copied macro enabled doc. Hit Ctrl+Insert Now."));
            // Get VBA parts from source document
            VbaProjectPart vbaSrc = srcDoc.MainDocumentPart.VbaProjectPart;
            VbaDataPart vbaDatSrc = vbaSrc.VbaDataPart;
            CustomizationPart keymapSrc = srcDoc.MainDocumentPart.CustomizationPart;
            // Create VBA parts in destination document
            VbaProjectPart vbaProjectPart1 = mainPart.AddNewPart<VbaProjectPart>("rId9");
            VbaDataPart vbaDataPart1 = vbaProjectPart1.AddNewPart<VbaDataPart>("rId1");
            CustomizationPart customKeyMapPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<CustomizationPart>("rId10");
            // Copy part contents
            vbaProjectPart1.FeedData(vbaSrc.GetStream());
            vbaDataPart1.FeedData(vbaDatSrc.GetStream());
            customKeyMapPart.FeedData(keymapSrc.GetStream());
            }
        }
    }
}
```